# Purpose of MethodCall list in Flutter plugin unit tests

Tags: plugins, flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

The default unit test setup when you create a plugin looks like this:

```
void main() {
  const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel(
      'com.example/my_plugin');

  setUp(() {
    channel.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      return '42';
    });
  });

  tearDown(() {
    channel.setMockMethodCallHandler(null);
  });

  test('getPlatformVersion', () async {
    expect(await MyPlugin.platformVersion, '42');
  });
}
```

However, in a lot of the source code I see people using a `List<MethodCall>` called `log`. Here is an [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/13e9bfcc94137fdef5dac40b7ece3fcc3daac6d3/packages/flutter/test/services/system_chrome_test.dart):

```
  test('setPreferredOrientations control test', () async {
    final List<MethodCall> log = <MethodCall>[];

    SystemChannels.platform.setMockMethodCallHandler((MethodCall methodCall) async {
      log.add(methodCall);
    });

    await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(<DeviceOrientation>[
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);

    expect(log, hasLength(1));
    expect(log.single, isMethodCall(
      'SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations',
      arguments: <String>['DeviceOrientation.portraitUp'],
    ));
  });
```

I understand the mocking with `setMockMethodCallHandler`, but why use a list of MethodCall when you could just use one? If it were just one case I wouldn't may much attention, but I see the pattern over and over in the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the point is to verify that the method call handler was triggered exactly once (and therefore added ("logged") exactly one entry into the `List<MethodCall>`).  If it were simply a `MethodCall` variable that changed from `null` to non-`null`, verifying that it was not triggered multiple times would be less straightforward.